# How to support italic font and bold font for Chinese

Tags: android, fonts

My android application will use Chinese. The regular font is OK, but the italic font and bold font does not work.

So which font files should I use for Chinese italic and bold font?

Comment: Does not work? How does it not work?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using `TextView` to show Chinese words.

If you want the whatever words in TextView to be bold or italic, it would be easy.
Just use

```
testView.getPaint().setFakeBoldText(true);
```

to make all words bold.

For italic, use:

```
testView.getPaint().setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
```

However, if you only want some words to be bold or italic. Normally you can set `StyleSpan` on specific range of your `Spannable`but it is not work on Chinese word.

Therefore, I suggest you create a class extends `StyleSpan`

```
public class ChineseStyleSpan extends StyleSpan{
    public ChineseStyleSpan(int src) {
        super(src);

    }
    public ChineseStyleSpan(Parcel src) {
        super(src);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        newApply(ds, this.getStyle());
    }
    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        newApply(paint, this.getStyle());
    }

    private static void newApply(Paint paint, int style){
        int oldStyle;

        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if(old == null)oldStyle =0;
        else oldStyle = old.getStyle();

        int want = oldStyle | style;
        Typeface tf;
        if(old == null)tf = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(want);
        else tf = Typeface.create(old, want);
        int fake = want & ~tf.getStyle(); 

        if ((want & Typeface.BOLD) != 0)paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        if ((want & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0)paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f); 
        //The only two lines to be changed, the normal StyleSpan will set you paint to use FakeBold when you want Bold Style but the Typeface return say it don't support it.
        //However, Chinese words in Android are not bold EVEN THOUGH the typeface return it can bold, so the Chinese with StyleSpan(Bold Style) do not bold at all.
        //This Custom Class therefore set the paint FakeBold no matter typeface return it can support bold or not.
        //Italic words would be the same

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Set this span to your Chinese words and I should be work.
Be aware to check it is only set on Chinese words only. I have not test on it but I can imagine that set fakebold on a bold English characters would be very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you don't use **bold** and *italic* fonts when displaying chinese text.

Bold is likely to distort the text and italic will only artificially skew the text.